# Add certain events from one Google Calendar to another

Tags: google-calendar, google-workspace-for-business

I as well as multiple other staff in my company have regular meetings. Is it possible to make a Google Calendar which gets automatically populated when one of us schedule a meeting for a particular date? In short, if I enter the key word "meeting" on a particular date on my calendar, can a second Google Calendar be populated with the same information on that particular date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a built-in feature.

One alternative is to use Google Apps Script to create a script called by a time-driven trigger to do that for you.